# display one to many linqdatasource joined table records in asp.net listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, data-binding

I am not well informed on asp.net databinding at all and can't find or figure how to databind sub-table records in a list view.  I have been able to link the table keys in the database, and the relationship was detected by the linqdatasource creation wizard.  The code below is as far/close as I have gotten, it yaks a 
"DataBinding: 'DynamicClass1' does not contain a property with the name 'prtitem'." error when the page is requested.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RecentMnBlg.aspx.cs" Inherits="rwhifonline.Prodtctvty.RecentMnBlg" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSourceNotesAndTags" runat="server" ContextTypeName="sitedbDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (PKID, NoteText, NoteTags)" TableName="Notes" OrderBy="PKID desc"></asp:LinqDataSource>
    <h3>notes</h3>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListViewNotes" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceNotesAndTags">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="item">
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="NoteTextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoteText") %>' />
                <br />
                PRTags:
                <!--<asp:Label ID="PRTagsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRTags") %>' /> -->
                <% var prtags = (IEnumerable)Eval("PRTags");
                    foreach (object prtitem in prtags) { %> 
                    <asp:Label ID="PRTagsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("prtitem.TagText") %>' />       
                <% } %>
                <br />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</asp:Content>
```

the commented bit displays:
"System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[NoteTag]" in the label
when the page is rendered without any of the foreach attempt section.

I have seen a few pages from searches about using a databound event that gets a list from a separate page call that returns a list of data items, but that seems excessive when there is a linq entity record right there.
any ideas or pointers about using those entities in databinding contexts?

Answer (score 0):

was able to call page code behind method with IList argument and return required string formatted list from each linq-ed record